# Node JS Auto Reload

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make a program with javascript or node.js what I want to achieve from the program is when there is a new item in rss that I take it will get a log through the terminal, and for the future I will put the code in firebase hosting, so I need that the code can run by itself the log that I will get maybe I will change it into a text file or stored in a database

so like this
I run the program and get all the items on RSS,
but when there is a new item I don't have to run the `node app.js` again, so every time there is a new item in the rss it will display the log by itself automatically

so far i made it with js node and i use [rss-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser)
and the code I use like this:

```
let Parser = require('rss-parser');
let parser = new Parser();

(async () => {
  let feed = await parser.parseURL('https://rss-checker.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss');
  feed.items.forEach(items => {
    console.log(items);
  })
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three common ways to achieve this:

- Polling
- Stream push
- Webhook

Based on your code sample I assume that the RSS feeder is request/response. This lends well to polling.

A poll based program will make a request to a resource on an interval. This interval should be informed by resource limits and expected performance from the end user. Ideally the API will accept an offset or a page so you could request all feeds above some ID. This make the program *stateful*.

`setInterval` can be used to drive the polling loop. Below shows an example of the poller loop with no state management. It polls at 5 second intervals:

```
let Parser = require('rss-parser');
let parser = new Parser(); 

setInterval(async () => {
  let feed = await parser.parseURL('https://rss-checker.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss');
  feed.items.forEach(items => {
    console.log(items);
  })
}), 5000);
```

This is incomplete because it needs to keep track of already seen posts. Creating a poll loop means you have a stateful process that needs to stay running.